# Rspec Ruby on rails tutorials

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec2, railstutorial.org

expect(page).to `have_title`

What is page in that, it says undefined local variable/method for **page**?

Below is the error I see.

> E:\Users\dheeraj\Desktop\rails_projects\sample_app>rspec spec/
>   ←[31mF←[0m←[32m.←[0m←[32m.←[0m←[32m.←[0m

Failures:

> 1) StaticPagesController GET 'home' should have the right title
>        ←[31mFailure/Error:←[0m ←[31mexpect(page).to have_title("Home")←[0m
>        ←[31mNameError←[0m:
>          ←[31m**undefined local variable or method `page' for #<RSpec::Core::Example Group::Nested_1::Nested_1:0x2e70778>←[0m** ←[36m     # ./spec/controllers/static_pages_controller_spec.rb:13:in`
>   block (3 l evels) in '←[0m
>
> Finished in 0.21701 seconds ←[31m4 examples, 1 failure←[0m
>
> Failed examples:
>
> ←[31mrspec ./spec/controllers/static_pages_controller_spec.rb:11←[0m
>   ←[36m# Stat icPagesController GET 'home' should have the right
>   title←[0m
>
> Randomized with seed 63847

Please help me to understand and resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

Page is used by capybara for request specs. I think you mistakenly assumed you can use page in your controller specs as well. Page is used to determine what page you are currently on.

I think this is the example spec you are looking for:

## spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb

```
it "should have the right title" do
  visit '/static_pages/home'
  expect(page).to have_title("Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | Home")
end
```

Comment: yes indeed it is---------Please suggest what method I should use in order to test this in place of expect(page), I am using Rails 4?                                                 it "should have the right title" do
  visit '/static_pages/home'
  expect(page).to have_title("Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | Home")
end

Comment: You can use this example in your request specs. You want to make sure the correct title is displayed, which means you want to test the behaviour of your views. The example in your controller spec can be removed, you shouldn't use page there.